# storage of fingerprint templates:Database or file options

Tags: database, file, biometrics

I have a project in which am developing a biometric authentication system for not less than 10000 users. Where exactly is the best point to save the fingerprint templates? From the scanner's manufacturer manuals, the templates are said to be similar to a 60 character password hash. Should is store them in a database table or should i create a file and write the template data on it? Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

A database is a better approach for future maintainability of your app. It also gives you better search performance out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.